# Data Mux SVA compare

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I've trouble designing assertions(SVA) for this scenario. 
When a mux sel is asserted, the data_in is expected to be stable for 2 clocks ; clock prior to mux sel being asserted, and the current clock when mux sel is asserted.

Now the data_in is a wide vector/bus signal, whereby some bits of the bus are Z and X during functional mode (this is expected), while this bits may carry value during non-functional mode.

This then implies, the approach to design the SVA would be to compare bit by bit of data bus when mux sel is asserted.

This is my approach, but SVA fails and am not sure why.

```
generate 
for( genvar i=1 ; i<BUS_WIDTH ; i++ ) begin  
    always @ (posedge clk) begin  
       if(!$isunknown(data_in[i]) && reset) begin  
           data_in_temp_prev[i]      <= data_in[i];  
           if (mux_sel==1 && reset==1 && i>0) begin  
             SVA_TEST: assert property (data_in[i] == data_in_temp_prev[i-1]) else `uvm_error("TRIAL_SVA",$sformatf("datain expected to be stable for 2 clks prior to mux sel"));  
            end //if  
        end //if isunknown  
        else begin  
            din0_temp_prev[i] <= 0;  
        end  
     end //always  
end // for genvar  
endgenerate
```

Any suggestions on how to approach designing this SVA ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem, you don't need all this structure for this kind of problem, look at my example below and tell me if helps or not.

```
property mux_compare;
    disable iff(!reset)
        @(posedge mux_sel)
            !$isunknown(data_in)
        |->
        @(posedge clk)
            $stable(data_in) [*2];
endproperty: mux_compare
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to SVA checkers is to use a standard structure to properties to avoid all kinds of problems. the structure is to always use clocked properties with "disable iff" and always use an implication operator, where the left hand side is the trigger and the right hand side is what we want to verify.
Here's an example from the LRM:

```
property abc(a, b, c);
  disable iff (c) @(posedge clk) a |=> b;
endproperty
```

similarly to the answer above, I would do this:

```
property mux_compare;
    disable iff(!reset)  @(posedge clk)
    mux_sel===1 |->  
    !$isunknown(data_in[i]) || $stable(data_in) && data_in[i] == $past(data_in[i],2);  
endproperty: mux_compare
```